# MMAP support in PHP compilation on windows

Tags: php, compilation, apc, mmap

I have successfully compiled PHP 5.4.7 on windows as per the instructions on php.net site. While I check the APC information in phpinfo(), it says MMAP support is disabled. Tried to use --enable-mmap on the configure command for php and it says 'unknown option'.

After a lot of search it looks like MMAP is a feature related to apache. I have the dependencies folder filled with the required apache headers and libs as per the compile instructions (also --enable-apache2handler and filter both work and generate the dll's).

I also looked inside the apache headers and it has "#define HAS_MMAP 1", so this should not be a problem.

So the question remains: how do I enable mmap support on php when I compile it on windows??